# PHP - How to get full path of subfolder or file in subfolder?

Tags: php, path, directory

I'm wondering how to get the full path to a subfolder or file, only by searching the name of the subfolder or the file itself.

I want to be able to add a directory, and add subdirectories in these in pretty much unlimited layers.

So if the first directory has the path of "Collections/Map1/", I'll need the full path to add as an example "Collections/Map1/Map2/". and so forth.

So in this case, is there a way to get the full path of "Map2", to be able to add a subfolder to it?

```
public function CreateDirectory(Folder $folder)
{   
    if(!mkdir(self::PATH . $folder->GetName()), 0777))
    {
        echo 'failed to create folder';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'folder created';
    }

}
```

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to know the entire path to the subfolder? I'm looking to be able to get the full path from just searching for a folder, as in me searching for "Map2" and be able to get the full path leading up to it. "Collections/Map1/Map2/" etc.

Comment: If you want to find a folder named 'Map2' without knowing any information about its location other than "it's in here somewhere" you're going to have to write some code to recurse through directories.